# how to install memcached PECL on centos 7 server

Tags: php, centos, memcached, pecl

I was trying to install Memcache PECL on my server. I installed memcached by this command

```
yum install memcached
```

and then used

```
yum install memcached php-pecl-memcache
```

to install php extension of memcache but had no luck on this installation

Please help me,

the error says

```
[root@localhost libmemcached-0.40]# yum install php php-pecl-memcached --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www3.atomicorp.com
 * base: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * epel: lug.mtu.edu
 * extras: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * updates: mirror-centos.hostingswift.com
Package php-5.4.41-47.el7.art.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:2.2.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-msgpack(x86-64) for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-igbinary(x86-64) for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
---> Package php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 0:1.2.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.2.1-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.2.1-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:2.2.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-msgpack.x86_64 0:0.5.5-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.5-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.5-5.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 0:1.2.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.2.1-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.2.1-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:2.2.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-msgpack.x86_64 0:0.5.5-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.5-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.5-5.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.4.41-47.el7.art will be installed

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch from base
    php-pecl-igbinary-1.2.1-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64 from epel
    php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.5-5.el7.x86_64 from epel
    php-process-5.4.41-47.el7.art.x86_64 from atomic
[root@localhost libmemcached-0.40]# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: download.fedora.redhat.com; Name or service not known
error: skipping http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm - transfer failed
[root@localhost libmemcached-0.40]# yum install memcached php-pecl-memcache memcached-selinux
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www3.atomicorp.com
 * base: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * epel: lug.mtu.edu
 * extras: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * updates: mirror-centos.hostingswift.com
Package memcached-1.4.24-5.el7.art.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package memcached-selinux available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.4.41-47.el7.art will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Installed: php-common-5.4.41-47.el7.art.x86_64 (@atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.19-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.20-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.21-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.22-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.23-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.24-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.25-25.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.3-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.4-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.5-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.6-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.7-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.8-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.9-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.35-41.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.36-42.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.37-43.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.38-44.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.39-45.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.40-46.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
           Installed: php-common-5.4.41-47.el7.art.x86_64 (@atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.19-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.20-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.21-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.22-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.23-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.24-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.25-25.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.3-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.4-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.5-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.6-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.7-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.8-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.9-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.35-41.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.36-42.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.37-43.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.38-44.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.39-45.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.40-46.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@localhost libmemcached-0.40]# yum install memcached php-pecl-memcache memcached-selinux
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www3.atomicorp.com
 * base: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * epel: lug.mtu.edu
 * extras: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * updates: mirror-centos.hostingswift.com
Package memcached-1.4.24-5.el7.art.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package memcached-selinux available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.4.41-47.el7.art will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Installed: php-common-5.4.41-47.el7.art.x86_64 (@atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.19-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.20-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.21-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.22-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.23-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.24-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.25-25.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.3-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.4-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.5-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.6-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.7-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.8-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.9-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.35-41.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.36-42.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.37-43.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.38-44.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.39-45.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.40-46.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-4.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
           Installed: php-common-5.4.41-47.el7.art.x86_64 (@atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.19-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.20-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.21-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.22-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.23-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.24-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php55-php-common-5.5.25-25.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.3-19.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.4-20.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.5-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.6-21.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.7-22.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.8-23.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: atomic-php56-php-common-5.6.9-24.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.35-41.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.36-42.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.37-43.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.38-44.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.39-45.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.40-46.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@localhost libmemcached-0.40]# yum install memcached php-pecl-memcache memcached-selinux
```